# What was that movie where a person puts a poison in all the drugs?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie a couple years ago in which a person puts a poison in all the drugs and the main characters have to infiltrate a facility to stop them. All I remember is a shot in which the camera shows a football stadium filled with cages with infected people within.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be a bit more specific about when you saw this?  Was this on TV, or a streaming service, or somewhere else?  What country/language?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like *[Kingsman: The Golden Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Golden_Circle)* (2017).

An excerpt from the Wikipedia synopsis:

> Merlin attempts to cure Harry's amnesia by flooding his bedroom—mirroring an element of Kingsman agent training—but the exercise fails. Eggsy eventually succeeds by threatening to shoot a Cairn Terrier puppy that resembles Harry's late dog, Mr Pickle, causing Harry to relive the final test of his Kingsman training in which he was ordered to shoot his dog. During their next mission, **Poppy broadcasts a message announcing she has added a toxin to all her drugs, which causes users to develop symptoms like Tequila's before succumbing to paralysis and, subsequently, death.** She offers the antidote to the world if the President of the United States will end the war on drugs and grant her cartel immunity from prosecution. **The President publicly negotiates, but secretly intends to let the infected die, as he is willing to eliminate all drug users and thus render Poppy's business useless. He quarantines many victims, including his chief of staff, in a stadium and leaves them there to die.**